# Generating random comments with python from a text source

Tags: python, regex, random, spinner

I read on wikipedia about [Article spinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_spinning) and I'm trying to create a function that does the same thing from a text source.

For example a text source could be:

```
{Hello|Hi|Howdy}{ ,I {really like|absolutely adore} your {picture|media|upload}|{, how are you?|, are you ok?}}
```

Some of the random comments that can be generated:

```
Hello, I really like your picture
Hi, I absolutely adore your upload
Hi, how are you?
and so on...
```

My main problem is reading the words between brackets. I'm currently using a text regex but python is only considering the first and the last bracket, so that's what I'm getting:

```
Hello|Hi|Howdy}{ ,I {really like|absolutely adore} your {picture|media|upload}|{, how are you?|, are you ok?}
```

Comment: please show your code or else we cannot really help you much. This seems like a classic greedy vs non-greedy regex problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it by myself.

```
def pick_random_word(self, match):
    words = match.group(1)
    return random.choice(words.split("|"))

def write_comment(self, comment):
    r = re.compile('{([^{}]*)}')
    while True:
        comment, n = r.subn(self.pick_random_word, comment)
        if n == 0:
            break
    print(comment)

#USAGE: self.write_comment("{{so|totally} ugly|very {nice|bad}} {photo|media|upload} {:)||:D|<3}")
```

It will print:

```
totally ugly photo 
so ugly media :D
very bad photo <3
and so on...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

list_a = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Howdy']
list_b = ['really like', 'absolutely adore']
list_c = ['picture', 'upload']

word_a = random.choice(list_a)
word_b = random.choice(list_b)
word_c = random.choice(list_c)

print "{0}, I {1} your {2}.".format(word_a, word_b, word_c)
```